# Adding a complete font-face

Tags: css, fonts

I have the following fonts in the `static/fonts/` directory:

```
Fontfabric---Mont-Thin.otf
Fontfabric---Mont-Thin-Italic.otf
Fontfabric---Mont-SemiBold.otf
Fontfabric---Mont-SemiBold-Italic.otf
```

Is there a way to add all of these fonts to a `custom.css` file using:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mont";
  src: "/static/fonts/Fontfabric---Mont-Thin.otf";
}
```

or do I have to add these all independently and specify that some are `thin` for example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each of them and specify a "weight" for every one.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Mont;
  src: url("/static/fonts/Fontfabric---Mont-Thin.otf");
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

or

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Mont;
   src: url("/static/fonts/Fontfabric---Mont-Thin.otf");
   font-weight: 400;
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)